# Полностью убрать расстояния между ячейками <td>

Tags: html, css

Существует некоторая таблица:

```css
td {
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      foo
    </td>
    <td>
      bar
    </td>
    <td>
      baz
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Необходимо полностью убрать отступы между ячейками в таблице.
У  изначально стоит `padding: 1px`. Это я убрал, но все равно между ячейками появляются отступы: у `<tr>` ширина - 65px (все тестил в FireFox), а суммарно у всех `<td>` - 61px. Что нужно сделать, чтобы не было вообще никаких отступов?

Comment: Да там ещё куча всяких свойств. cell padding, collapse что-то такое

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ntLzdf5m/1/

Answer (score 6):

Первое свойство - расстояние между ячейками.
Второе - предотвращает задвоение рамок.

```
table{
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Ну да все работает, спасибо, у самого возникал такой вопрос как то https://jsfiddle.net/72eg3o9x/

Answer (score 4):

Почти как у остальных, но `border-spacing` не нужен при `border-collapse: collapse`:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      foo
    </td>
    <td>
      bar
    </td>
    <td>
      baz
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      foo
    </td>
    <td>
      bar
    </td>
    <td>
      baz
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Этот метод стал deprecated как минимум лет пять назад

Comment: @ru_volt "А я до сих пор поезда взрываю."

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить отступы и толщину границы:

```
margin: 0px;
border-width: 0px;
```

Также и для таблицы.

Comment: не помогает: https://jsfiddle.net/ntLzdf5m/

Answer (score 0):

Полный ответ на ваш вопрос выглядит так:

```
// Remove default spacing
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

// Remove default padding
td, th {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: `text-align: center;` - откуда взялся?

Comment: @VenZell, угадай с одной попытки. Строка 227.